# JavaScript: Перебор всех вариантов

Tags: javascript, массивы, алгоритм, комбинаторика

Как из такого массива получить массив с полным перебором всех вариантов?

```js
var myArray = [
  [1],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2]
];
```

Т.е. должно получиться вот так:

```js
var res = [
  [1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 2],
  [1, 2, 1],
  [1, 2, 2],
  [1, 3, 1],
  [1, 3, 2]
];
```

Длина исходного массива `myArray` может быть другой.

```js
var myArray = [
  [1],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2]
];

var length = myArray.length;
var rowsCount = 1;
myArray.map(function(item) {
  rowsCount *= item.length;
});

var res = [], i, j;

for (i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++) {
  // all needed rows 1...6
  for (j = 0; j < length; j++) {
    // walk through arrays 0,1,2
  }
  res.push([]);
}

console.log(res.length);
```

Comment: То есть из исходного массива нужно получить все уникальные элементы, а затем из этих уникальных элементов нужно создать массив массивов (размерность одного массива равна размерности количества уникальных элементов), а размерность основного массива - это выборка из теории вероятности, причем не простая, а зависящая от порядка...хм, думаю вам нужно в теорию вероятности немного углубиться.

Comment: связанный: [Декартово произведение нескольких массивов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/778359/227016)